# AWS CloudSearch: The value of [fieldname] cannot be a JSON array or object

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-cloudsearch, aws-sdk

I am having this issue with a field of type int-array. Using the aws-sdk for Node.js, I am submitting a document via the *CloudSearchDomain.uploadDocuments()* method. The JSON for the document (in the *searchContent* variable) is created in the node process, then I use:

```
var params = {
  contentType: 'application/json',
  documents: JSON.stringify([searchContent])
};
csd.uploadDocuments(params, function(err, data){
  ...(callback process)...
});
```

The non-stringified *searchContent* object looks like this:

```
{ id: 1,
  type: 'Product',
  hash_type_id: 'Product-1',
  name: 'Test product',
  description: 'A test product',
  category: [ 2 ],
  content: '<some text here>',
  state: [ 1 ],
  hash_all: '<some text>'
}
```

and stringified like this:

```
[{"id":1,"type":"Product","hash_type_id":"Product-1","name":"Test product","description":"A test product","content":" <some text>","category":[2],"state":[1],"hash_all":"<some text>"}]
```

The error I am getting is:

```
{
  "message": "{ [\"The value of category cannot be a JSON array or object\"] }",
  "code": "DocumentServiceException",
  "time": "2014-11-20T01:24:27.499Z",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false
}
```

As mentioned, the category field is int-array type. Why would I be getting this message?

**UPDATE:** I have also tried using a typed array (Int16Array) for the category field, with exactly the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The document needs to be wrapped in the batch processing parameters. In a batch, each document needs to have this format:

```
{
  type: "add|update|delete",
  id: "Unique ID",
  fields: Document JSON here
}
```

And this needs to be in an array, even if it's just a single document. So the JSON for the document in the question becomes:

```
{
  type: "add",
  id: "Product-1",
  fields: { id: 1,
    type: 'Product',
    hash_type_id: 'Product-1',
    name: 'Test product',
    description: 'A test product',
    category: [ 2 ],
    content: '<some text here>',
    state: [ 1 ],
    hash_all: '<some text>'
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see AWS CloudSearch support `update` type for uploaded documents. There are only `add` and `delete` types. If the document with defined `id` already exists, it will be overwritten (/updated). Referring to Amazon Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/preparing-data.html#adding-documents

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. can someone help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43945038/aws-cloudsearch-upload-json-value-tag-cannot-be-array-or-object